# Finding a certain character and deleting it while loop

Tags: php

i'm trying to find a certain character from a full text and remove that character and store it in variables

Example;

```
$text = ',this,is,an,example,'; //dynamic texts always changable
```

i'm trying to remove all comma's(,) from the text and store it in variables so it will be look like

```
$text1 = 'this';
$text2 = 'is';
$text2 = 'an';
$text2 = 'example';
```

So far what i've learned and done following

```
$text = ',this,is,an,example,';
$position = 0;
while (($position = strpos($text, ",", $position)) !== false){
  echo "Found $position<br>";
  $position++;
}
```

so what kind of method should i watch here is there any other methods to do this thank you.

Comment: Why not use an array?

Comment: `preg_split` or `explode` spring to mind here

Comment: array can be used also doesnt matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `array` would help -

```
$text = ',this,is,an,example,';

$texts = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $text)));
// explode - split string by ,
// trim - to remove blank spaces from start & end
// array_filter - remove empty values
```

**Output**

```
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  string(4) "this"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "is"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "an"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "example"
}
```

If the variables needed then -

```
$texts = array_values($texts); // to reset the keys and start from 0
foreach ($texts as $i => $t) {
    ${'text' . ($i + 1)} = $t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in below manner...

```
$text = ',this,is,an,example,';

$textArr =  explode(',', $text);

extract($textArr , EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "text");

echo '<br/>'.$text_1;
echo '<br/>'.$text_2;
echo '<br/>'.$text_3;
echo '<br/>'.$text_4;
```